# Image require(url) from object doesn't display in React

Tags: reactjs, image, object, url, require

In Data.js I have this object with few props:

```
export const DataInfo = {
    image: require('../../assets/internet-marketing.svg'),
    alt: 'internet marketing',
    id: 'e-marketing',
    upperText: 'e-marketing solutions',
    title: 'Professional interactive development',
    description: 'Quisque condimentum, diam ut placerat egestas, lectus est semper quam, nec accumsan magna enim eget dui.',
    primary:true
};
```

in pages/index.js I import and spread it:

```
import { DataInfo } from '../components/DataInfo/Data';

<DataInfo {...DataInfo} />
```

in DataInfo/index.js I destructure the props and use it to display the image:

```
const DataInfo = (
     { image, alt, id, upperText, title, description, primary }) => {
    return (
        <>    
                     
             <Image src={image}  alt={alt} />
                                       
        </>
    )
}
```

But the image doesn't display. The path is correct, as I tested it, and I have no error message.

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

If you inspect the `img` tag or `console.log`, the image source probably will be different from what you are trying to apply. It happens because when the project is built, webpack will correctly move the images into the build folder and provide us with correct paths.

#### Possible solutions

1. Use a public image

   `public` folder

   ```
   require('/images/imagename.png')
   ```
2. Import the image as a React Component

   ```js
   import { ReactComponent as Image } from '../../assets/imagename.png' 

   function Something() {
     return <Image />
   }
   ```

**Note:** Importing as a React Component, you don't need to create an `img` tag or even `image` on your object

**Note 2:** Using the 2nd solution is better, because when it converts into a React Component, it can also reduce your file size

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. The first one worked well for me. I get the image url from a public address. The second one is a good one too, but it doesn't work well in the context of my project.

Comment: Glad to help you.
**Hint:** To register your question as closed, select my answer as helpful and click the check button